# setText issue at android activity

Tags: android

I have a problem within an activity.

I have a list view populated by JSON. If the user taps on a row a detail view activity is shown. On this detail view activity is a problem at four of the lines, that I have commented (//) to avoid the exception. Here you have the code of the detail view activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Empresas_SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String valoracionEmpresa;
    String nombreEmpresa;
    String direccionEmpresa;
    String imagenstrImagen;
    String position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.empresas_singleitemview);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        valoracionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("valoracionEmpresa");


        // Get the result of country
        nombreEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("nombreEmpresa");


        // Get the result of population
        direccionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("direccionEmpresa");


        // Get the result of flag
        imagenstrImagen = i.getStringExtra("strImagen");


        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

  //  *** this are the four lines that throw exception if not commented, each of them.

            // Set results to the TextViews
 (1)        //txtvaloracionempresa.setText(valoracionEmpresa);
 (2)        //txtnombreempresa.setText(nombreEmpresa);
 (3)        //txtdireccionempresa.setText(direccionEmpresa);

            // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
            // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
  (4)       //imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagenstrImagen, imagenEmpresa);
    }
}
```

I need your help to detect where is the problem. Thank you

EDITED

This is layout empresas_singleintemview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/strImagen"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/direccionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nombreEmpresa"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombreEmpresa"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="5:45"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDITED

Code for the list adapter:

mport java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class Empresas_ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Empresas_ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView valoracionEmpresa;
        TextView nombreEmpresa;
        TextView direccionEmpresa;
        ImageView strImagen;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empresas_listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        valoracionEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        nombreEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        direccionEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        strImagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        valoracionEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.VALORACIONEMPRESA));
        nombreEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.NOMBREEMPRESA));
        direccionEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.DIRECCIONEMPRESA));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.STRIMAGEN), strImagen);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Empresas_SingleItemView.class);
                Log.v("MVASCO valoracion Empresa =", "HOLA NOBMRE "+resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.NOMBREEMPRESA));
                Log.v("MVASCO valoracion Empresa =", "HOLA VALORACION"+resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.VALORACIONEMPRESA));

                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("valoracionEmpresa", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.VALORACIONEMPRESA));

                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("nombreEmpresa", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.NOMBREEMPRESA));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("direccionEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.DIRECCIONEMPRESA));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("strImagen", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.STRIMAGEN));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would run a debug with breakpoints at your string sets and finding your resources by id, either your strings are null, or the views themselves are. Can we see your layout file?

Comment: Are those `View`s defined in your `empresas_singleitemview` file?

Comment: @zgc7009, yes of course,  I will post it in my answer.

Comment: Also, could you please add the code where you store the variables into your `Intent`?

Comment: Can you post empresas_singleitemview.xml and the code where you add the strings to the Intent object?

Comment: @nKn, I have logged the variables received from the previos activity , and they are ok. But I will post the code for you, no problem

Comment: Make sure you are not getting null while extracting string here: getStringExtra. Same at other places.

Comment: It has to be in getting your strings from your intent bundle, your views look good

Comment: @zgc7009, the variables passed by the intents are logged and they are OK. I have posted  layout and list adapter

Comment: @Aashish, i have logged the received variables, and they are all ok.

Comment: Have you run a log on it in your Empresas_SingleItemView activity after you get them from your bundle to make sure they are set? Try, just for testing, doing ""your view name".setText("Random string"); and see if it still gives you a problem If it does, it is with your views, if not it is with your strings.

Comment: @zgc7009, yes, the problem is not at the strings from the bundle.

Comment: @zgc7009, good idea, i will check it now

Comment: @zgc7009, i have uncomment line: txtnombreempresa.setText("hola"); and the log cat set the exception at that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your error is in your id's for your views. You have

```
<!-- Title Of Song-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

but then

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombreEmpresa"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="5:45"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

with the same id. You also have

```
TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
```

with no actual TextView with the id `nombreEmpresa`. Either remove the duplicate view or give it a new id (likely nombreEmpresa).

Sorry for not catching the error earlier

Comment: That was, two days fighting against that problem and was so simple. THANK YOU

Comment: No worries, it is an easy mistake to make. It is worth noting that Android will consider any id in it's resource file as valid, so just because it says that R.id."name" works doesn't mean that the view is actually currently accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like culprit is this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/direccionEmpresa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/nombreEmpresa"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

<!-- Rightend Duration -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/valoracionEmpresa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/nombreEmpresa"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="5:45"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

You have given `same id` to two `TextView`.

Comment: Same answer than zgc7009, but he was first, thank you very much for your time and effort.